# visual studio code error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, centos

I have installed visual studio code in my centos7 system plus python and jupyter extensions, then I tried to do a simply test like: 3+2 in vs code by using jupyter extension. It shows me such error:
**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**
I really have no idea about this problem. Could someone do me a favor? Thanks a million!

Sihan

Comment: sounds like a JavaScript error on a function that does not return a Thenable/Promise. Have you read the VSC doc about Jupyter

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on VS Code 1.54.3, switching to [VS Code insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) fixed it for me.

It seems like the underlying problem is currently tracked in this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4976), in particular see a more detailed summary in my [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4976#issuecomment-801617832).